# Object name from array value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I have array with some values :

```
let typeArray = ["name", "strret", "car", "type"];
```

And I have one object :

```
let formDefinitionObject = {schema:{}}
```

I want the `formDefinitionObject` object be like :

```
let formDefinitionObject = {
  schema: {
    name: {
      type: 'string',
      title: 'Name',
      required: true
    },
    strret: {
      type: 'string',
      title: 'Strret'
    },
    car: {
      type: 'string',
      title: 'Car'
    },
    type: {
      type: 'string',
      title: 'Type'
    }
  }
}
```

I want dynamically for each item in array to be object in `formDefinitionObject.schema` object. For example if i add one more item in array `typeArray.push('country')` to automatic add this object in formDefinitionObject.schema object.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck (and also what logic tells you that `name` should have `required: true` but none of the others should). People will be glad to help.

Comment: Have you tried using a `for` loop? And how do you decide which items should be `required`?

Comment: But how do you decide that a field has to be `required` ? And does the `type` has to be `string` for like every field ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't understand how `required: true` would fit in. Remaining things can be done as follows

```js
var getFormDefinition = function(arr) {
  function getSchemaObj(arr) {
    return arr.map(d => ({
        [d]: {
          type: typeof(d),
          title: d
        }
      }))
      .reduce((a, b) => ({ ...a, ...b }))
  }

  var schemaObj = getSchemaObj(arr)

  arr.push = function(...d) {
    Object.assign(schemaObj, getSchemaObj(d))

    return Array.prototype.push.call(arr, ...d)
  }
  return ({
    schema: schemaObj
  })
}

var typeArray = ["name", "strret", "car", "type"];
var result = getFormDefinition(typeArray)
console.log(result)

typeArray.push('nitish')
console.log(result)
```

---

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Proxy` on the `typeArray` with the `set` trap so each time you push new value to the proxy array you can also add new property to your schema. This way you can simulate observer pattern.

You can also create some pattern to add additional properties like `required` for example `name:prop1:prop2` but this way value is fixed to `true`.

```js
let typeArray = ["name:required", "strret", "car", "type"];
let formDefinitionObject = {
  schema: {}
}

let proxyArray = new Proxy(typeArray, {
  set(obj, prop, value) {
    if (prop != 'length') addToSchema(formDefinitionObject.schema, value);
    return Reflect.set(...arguments);
  }
})

function capitalize(string) {
  return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}

function addToSchema(schema, prop) {
  const [name, ...params] = prop.split(':');
  schema[name] = {
    type: 'string',
    title: capitalize(name)
  }
  params.forEach(param => schema[name][param] = true);
  return schema;
}

proxyArray.reduce(addToSchema, formDefinitionObject.schema);

proxyArray.push('email:required:isEmail');
proxyArray.push('phone');

console.log(formDefinitionObject)
```

**Update**: You could use something like this `name:prop1|value:prop2` to add property value other then `true` but if you don't specify value default is still `true`

```js
let typeArray = ["name:required", "strret", "car", "type"];
let formDefinitionObject = {
  schema: {}
}

let proxyArray = new Proxy(typeArray, {
  set(obj, prop, value) {
    if (prop != 'length') addToSchema(formDefinitionObject.schema, value);
    return Reflect.set(...arguments);
  }
})

function capitalize(string) {
  return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}

function addToSchema(schema, prop) {
  const [name, ...params] = prop.split(':');
  schema[name] = {
    type: 'string',
    title: capitalize(name)
  }

  params.forEach(param => {
    const [key, value] = param.split('|');
    schema[name][key] = value ? value : true 
  });
  return schema;
}

proxyArray.reduce(addToSchema, formDefinitionObject.schema);

proxyArray.push('email:required:isEmail');
proxyArray.push('phone:default|123/555-333:required');
proxyArray.push('address')

console.log(formDefinitionObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though you did not clarify more how a field has to be `required` or does any field has to be as `string`, here's a solution based on what you provided so far.

The next snippet does the job and it has some explanations :

```js
let typeArray = ['name', 'strret', 'car', 'type'],
  formDefinitionObject = {
    schema: {}
  };

/** cycle through "typeArray" and populate "formDefinitionObject.schema" **/
typeArray.forEach(el => {

  let currObj = {
    type: 'string', /** YOU DID NOT SPECIY HOW TO DECIDE THE TYPE **/
    title: el[0].toUpperCase() + el.substring(1), /** the title with the first letter being capitalized as you provided in the question. You can just use "el" instead of "el[0].toUpperCase() + el.substring(1)" if you'd like to print as it is **/
  };

  el === 'name' && (currObj['required'] = true); /** YOU DID NOT SPECIY HOW TO DECIDE IF A FIELD HAS TO BE REQUIRED. I just saw only the "name" as required so I did a basic (yet a stupid) check if the current element is "name" add a required to it **/
  
  formDefinitionObject.schema[el] = currObj; /** add the current record to the "schema" attribute **/

});


console.dir(formDefinitionObject); /** printing the result **/
```

I'll be here if you answer our questions in the comments section.

Til then, hope I pushed you further.